# make GHC to do more GCs?

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection, ghc

In order to obtain a more accurate measure of the maximium live size of some programs, I'd like to have the runtime system to do more frequent garbage collections. Are there flags to GHC that directly/indirectle result in more GCs? I know inserting `performGC` can achive that to some extent, but there are quite a few programs to instrument.

Comment: Playing with [GC settings](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html) is probably not a good way to measure memory usage - the results can still be imprecise. Please look at [GHC memory profiling page](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/prof-heap.html).

Comment: @RafałRawicki Profiling isn't an option for me because it interferes with optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For direct increase in GCs you can set the `-Iseconds` flag to something lower than 0.3 to increase the frequency of idle GC. You can also set `-c` to use a compacting algo which should generally reduce memory usage (to give a closer approx to actual memory used rather than GC overhead). You may also want to set `-Asize` to something lower than 512k, which by giving a smaller allocation area should generally increase the no. of GCs.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against forcing a higher frequency of GCs unless you specifically know a better suited GC-tuning for your code. GC runs can be very expensive.

Yes, your program uses "too much" memory, but this lenience is what makes the GC perform well. If you allow an overhead of 2-3 times of the memory that is strictly needed (*do not know figures for GHCs GC though*), GC runs can be scheduled much more infrequently.

You say you do not want to turn on memory profiling, because it interferes with optimizations, but forcing the GC may be worse. If you increase the pressure on the heap too much, you may end up benchmarking GC runs.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make this clear, but this is not a performance issue. My sole purpose is to obtain a more accurate measurement of the live size. The runtime system gets stats of live size from GC, so more frequent GC means more points of measure. I don't care if the overall performance gets worse as long as the measurement is better.

Comment: @rem: OK, I misunderstood that. In another comment you said that profiling interferes with optimization, you I assumed that it was about performance. You might still want to check whether profiling really costs too much performance if you compile only with `-prof` but do not annotate any cost centres. Then run with e.g. `+RTS -hb`. Add `-i` to control the sampling interval.

Comment: "You might still want to check whether profiling really costs too much performance" in that regard, "cost too much performance" means its overhead on live size over the real live size. But then how does one tell if there's no more accurate measurement of the real live size?